# SELECT list expression references column xxx which is neither grouped nor aggregated at, why need to use subquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I'm kinda new to SQL and been following some tutorial courses online.
I want to compare the **num_bikes_available** at a station to the **average num_bikes_available**.
My question is why cant it just show the average using the OUTER SELECT clause? Why do it need to be done using SUBQUERY? [My Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhyJr.png). [Tutorial Answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aEM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `SELECT AVG(num_bikes_available) FROM citibike_stations` will return a single row with average calculated over all rows.

Now, if you add `station_id` like `SELECT station_id, AVG(num_bikes_available) FROM citibike_stations`, this is also supposed to return a single row, but BigQuery does not know which exactly `station_id` value do you need. Therefore you see that error.

BigQuery can show average for every distinct `station_id` value it finds, but to do that it needs the `GROUP BY` clause like `SELECT station_id, AVG(num_bikes_available) FROM citibike_stations GROUP BY station_id`.